# So I managed to restore from an "Inaccessible Boot device" error after update ... now what?

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-update, bsod

Due to a busy schedule, I have turned on my windows 10 PC for the first time in a month. Of course I had a lot of updates waiting for me.

One of the updates was the February cumulative one (plus other security related... I don't know the exact culprit). The update went seemingly ok,but I got a BSOD at restart, with the **Inacessible Boot Device** error message (no further hex code were given, only a QR code and a link to windows.com/stopcode).

I tried a bit of command prompt magic, looking for some update still pending. The specific checks where [something like this](https://www.windowsblogitalia.com/2017/10/soluzione-inaccessible-boot-device-windows-10-update-cumulativo/):

```
  reg load hklm\temp c:\windows\system32\config\software
  reg delete “HKLM\temp\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\SessionsPending” /v Exclusive
  reg unload HKLM\temp
```

followed by

```
 dism /image:C:\ /get-packages
 MKDIR C:\temp\packages
 dism /image:c:\ /remove-package /packagename:PACKAGEIDENTITYNAME /scratchdir:c:\temp\packages
```

where PACKAGEIDENTITYNAME was supposed to be any package with status "Install pending". But there were none: everything was "Installed".
I tried all the same to remove-package all the packages installed during the day: I was able to remove some Fixup... but then I met a package which couldn't be removed (I suppose it is the cumulative update).

The boot device was still inaccessible, so I went for another approach and restored from a prior image which had been kept by the updater before installing (good job!) and disabled the automatic updates following [microsoft suggestions](https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/help/14238/windows-10-troubleshoot-blue-screen-errors).

Now everything is in working order but of course I don't have installed the updates.

**The question is: what can I do to be able to keep my machine updated?**

I fear that when I will turn the updates back on, I will blue-screen again.

Should (can?) I signal to microsoft that something in the update was not working for me? Have I to *hope* that some new cumulative update will fix the errors? Was some telemetry already sent so they are already busy working on it?

Comment: Try the updates again first to prove that it wasn't a one-off error. Do them one by one to isolate them if you prefer.

Comment: Probably download the updates at the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx)? Try to install the updates one-by-one and check to see which update caused the BSOD and report it to Microsoft.

Comment: How do you report such a thing to Microsoft?